# Pointer Lock does Not Work on Android Browsers (official demo)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile, pointerlock

This is the online demo suggested by MDN:

1. https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/pointer-lock/

It works on desktop, but not on mobile (Chrome, Edge, FF).
Meanwhile, the pointer lock API is listed as widely supported on mobile:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API

more demos:

2. Quake 3 WebGL demo
   http://media.tojicode.com/q3bsp/
3. http://www.smartjava.org/examples/pointerlock/

I implemented it myself too, and when I used JSON.stringify(e) to read the contents of the error event, I got: '{isTrusted:true}'

**UPDATE:**
I used a more complex function to serialize the whole event object, so after adding the suggested by MDN event listeners:

```
document.addEventListener('pointerlockerror', lockError, false);
document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockerror', lockError, false);
```

and

```
function lockError(e) {
  serializeEvent(e)
}
```

I got from the serialize function:

[image: the error returned]

**UPDATE #2:**
I included FF as it doesn't work either, it just **doesn't raise an error**, while it follows pointer erratically (at high speed), without locking it and while firing the pointerlockchange event!

Comment: Can you share the full error text?

Comment: That's all I got. I tried: alert(JSON.stringify({e})); and I got: {"e":{"isTrusted":true}} when I clicked with the bluetooth pointing device.

Comment: @VijayDev
I managed to get the whole event object, see the edited question.